# How to translate yup errors with next18-next?

Tags: localization, internationalization, next.js, yup

How can I translate yup errors with next18-next since it should be server-side rendered?

Is it possible to use placeholders in next18-next translations strings?

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple to solve this.

validate.ts:

```js
export const setValidationTranslations = (t: TFunction) => {
  const required = t("required");
  const minString = t("min_string");
  const maxString = t("max_string");
  const emailValid = t("email_valid");
  const minNumber = t("min_number");
  const maxNumber = t("max_number");

  setLocale({
    mixed: {
      required: required,
    },
    string: {
      min: minString,
      max: maxString,
      email: emailValid,
    },
    number: {
      min: minNumber,
      max: maxNumber,
    },
  });
};

export const schema = () => {
  return object().shape({
    email: string().email().required(),
    password: string().required().min(6),
  });
};
```

Page.tsx:

```js
import {
  setValidationTranslations,
  schema,
} from "./validate";

function Page() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
  setValidationTranslations(t);
  ...
}
```

common.json with default yup texts:

```json
{
  "required": "${path} is a required field",
  "email_valid": "${path} must be a valid email",
  "min_string": "${path} must be at least ${min} characters",
  "max_string": "${path} must be at most ${max} characters",
  "min_number": "${path} must be greater than or equal to ${min}",
  "max_number": "${path} must be less than or equal to ${max}"
}
```

Comment: This will potentially call setValidationTranslations a lot of times for no real purpose. Shouldn't it be called in a useEffect hook that only runs once on mount?

Comment: Also, this is a problem for schema-specific values.

Comment: It is also a problem when you have different schemas.